# How can I remove this text in my integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is my terminal currently:

[image: Terminal]

I tried removing the file path using code-runner's settings

```
@ext:formulahendry.code-runner
```

then add

```
cls &&
```

to both c and c++ file paths. When I saved and run my code again, the file path was gone, most of it. For some reason this text still pops up, how can I remove this in my terminal?

Comment: If the “this text” refers to the warning message from the compiler, fix the warning.

Comment: try writing 'int main()' instead of 'main()' in C program

Comment: don't compile your code